# Why would Visual Studio 2010 (Intellisense) stop generating an interface pointer?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

I had working code that implemented a wrapper and interface along the lines of:

```
public class wrapper : wrapperInterface {
    ...
}
```

Intellisense was generating a wrapperInterfacePtr so that in a C++ header I had a valid statement of:

```
wrapper::wrapperInterfacePtr m_wrapper;
```

I was mucking around trying to add some Delegate functionality so I could pass a C++ callback into the C# (I failed), and at some point during the mucking around the auto-generated wrapperInterfacePtr became undefined.  Even after I returned all the code to (what appears) to be its original state, Intellisense is not generating wrapperInterfacePtr.

Any thoughts on how what I could have done, or how to kick-start Intellisense?

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

No, really.  Try restarting VS and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: Is `wrapperInterfacePtr` just `typedef wrapperInterface* wrapperInterfacePtr`? Where was it being generated?

Comment: @Donnelle unfortunately, restarting this morning did not reset anything.  I was hopeful too!

Comment: @Dai I seem to remember it was a typedef, but not anything so simple.  For instance, when I choose one of the still existing auto-generated elements '_wrapperInterface' (note the underscore) the mouseover shows the element as 'typedef _com_ptr_t<com_IIID<wrapper::_wrapper, &__uuidof(wrapper::_wrapper)>> wrapper_wrapperPtr.

Comment: I'm getting more convinved its an Intellisense/reset issue as one of the items that still gets auto-generated is 'cbDelegate'.  That was the name of a delegate that is now commented out.  I performed a clean before the rebuild, is there anything else I can do to "flush the project cache"?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work again.  I can't give the definitive reason it failed, but I have an idea.  The new c# managed code is on top of a huge library of existing C++ unmanaged code. I build the managed code using VS and then use an in-house tool to build everything else.  The in-house build tool doesn't do a clean unless you really, really force the issue.  (It would take days.)  When I did a build-clean on the dlls that interfaced with the managed code, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. These sort of things can be so frustrating!